# Does an analytic continuation for a particular Leibniz series exist?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-continuation

Define a Leibniz series as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
L(x) & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}e^{-kx}\ln k,\ \ x>0
\end{eqnarray*}

I have two questions: (I) Is there an explicit formula for $L(x)$?
(II) Does the analytic continuation for $L(x)$ from region $x>0$
to region $x<0$ exist?

Comment: I can show  [that $L^{(k)}(0)  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} L^{(k)}(x)  = -\eta'(-k)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896694/showing-etas-lim-z-to-1-sum-n-1-infty-zn-n-s)

Answer (score 2):

For $0 < |z| < 1$ and $\Re(s) > 1$

$$F(s,z) = \Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n n^{-s} =\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx} z^n dx= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x/z-1}dx$$ 
$$= \frac{ x^s/s}{1/z-1}+\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \left(\frac{1}{e^x/z-1}- \frac{1_{x < 1}}{1/z-1}\right)dx $$

And this integral is well-defined and analytic for  $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [1,\infty),\Re(s) > -1$ as well as $\frac{F(s,z)}{\Gamma(s)}$

Finally

$$G(y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-ny} \log n=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{-F(s,-e^{-y})}{\Gamma(s)}|_{s=0}$$

is analytic for $-e^{-y} \not \in [1,\infty)$.

If you want to move the branch cut, try a change of contour $$F(s,z) =  \int_0^\infty  \frac{(\gamma(t))^{s-1}}{e^{\gamma(t)}/z-1}\gamma'(t)dt$$

where $\gamma$ is a curve from $0 \to \infty$, it will move the branch cut  to $e^{-\gamma(.)}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* evaluates the series as
$$-\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,-e^{-x}\right).$$

Comment: @IgorRivin_Thank you very much. Maybe I have one naive question. I konw what
$\mathrm{PolyLog}[0,-e^{-x}]$ means, but I do not know what $\mathrm{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}[0,-e^{-x}]$
means. So can you tell me what $\mathrm{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}[0,-e^{-x}]$
means ? (I'm sorry that I'm a fresh in Mathematica.)

Comment: $\text{PolyLog}(p,-e^{-x})$ would be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k e^{-kx} k^{-p}$.  $\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}(0,-e^{-x})$ would be the partial derivative of this with respect to $p$ at $p=0$.

Comment: Mathematica calls it the *Nielsen generalized polylogarithm*

Answer (score 1):

Igor Rivin already gave Mathematica's answer to the first question.  As to the second: yes, $\text{PolyLog}(p,z)$ has a logarithmic branch point at $z=1$ (corresponding to $x=n\pi i$ for odd $n$); you can analytically continue around these to the rest of the complex plane.  Of course the continuation is not unique: if you want a single-valued version, there will be branch cuts.  And similarly you can analytically continue the derivative with respect to $p$.